# What's the use of the oauth_token_secret in Twitter OAuth?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I followed the tutorial on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter to use `OAuth` on my homepage. Everything worked and after the last step I have an `oauth_token` (after converting it to an access token) and an `oauth_token_secret`. Now I want to post a new status on twitter. So I did everything on this page https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request which is just a post request to /1/statuses/update.json. On that page nothing is said about the `oauth_token_secret`, so I haven't used it in my request and just have put the `oauth_token` in it. After submitting the post request twitter gives me the status code 401 Unauthorized. Why that? Do I have to use the `oauth_token_secret` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token secret is used to hash the signature base. Something like a password. You don't send the password, you use it to compute a secure hash of the thing the service sent to you.  You send that secure hash, then the service checks that secure hash against the request you sent. If they match, you're authorized.

The gory details are described in the OAuth spec, [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).

Twitter uses OAuth1.0a, but is mostly consistent with that spec.

here's the relevant bit:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.2

[image]

Comment: OK, this ist what I am doing and it doesn't work.
My header field Authorization has these values: oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_callback, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_version, oauth_token and oauth_signature. In this case oauth_token is NOT the oauth_token_secret but the access token which I get after a request to /oauth/access_token. For the oauth_signature the key is consumer_secret&oauth_token_secret (everything escaped) and the text consists of all the values listed above after being escaped and sorted. Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: yes, well. The oauth spec is pretty particular, and little deviances cause "401 unauthorized" with no indication of the problem. For example, the sig base needs to have all those oauth elements sorted. And: The constituents of the key need to be urlencoded, but not the ampersand between them.  Also the encoding is not according to the HTTP spec but must use a OAuth-specific  url encoding (uppercase only, etc). And then you take the ascii encoding of *that*. The signature method must be HMAC-SHA1 (I think). Lots of  details, easy to get one thing wrong. Hard to diagnose.

Comment: ps: your original question, *Do I have to use the oauth_token_secret somewhere?* makes me think you haven't really understood how Twitter's oauth works. It may require you to go back and take a closer look at the doc and your code.

Comment: OK, there it is. I forgot to put the status message into the signature base. Now everything works. Thanks for your help!