# How to access a user's Gmail account from a web application?

Tags: php, oauth, gmail

I am building a CRM webapp in PHP that will pull from all of a user's email and social media accounts, and allow them to read and respond to all their emails, or compose new ones.  Right now, I am just trying to get this working with Gmail using OAuth 1.0, but I'm having some trouble.

I can get the request token and the authorize token successfully and once the user authorizes me, Google redirects back to my app like it's supposed to... but now how do I actually pull messages from the user's inbox?  [This link](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/oauthimap) says I need to make a call using the user's email to get access to their inbox, but how do I get the user's email address?  What do I do with the oauth_verifier and oauth_token that Google returns to me?

Comment: Wouldn't you get it from, well, the user? I fail to understand what you mean. If I understand correctly, you're making what amounts to a more basic Outlook Web Access. Then shouldn't you already have the user's email (because, you know, he would've needed it to set up)?

Comment: The main problem, Aaron, is you've shown no code. Show us what you've tried so far so that we have a point of reference in which we can guide you to where you need to go. Otherwise, you're asking us to start from scratch and give you information that you'll needlessly respond with "yeh but i know that alredy!". Click the [edit] link to add the missing information to your question. Good luck! :)

Comment: No, the user never enters their email or password on my app and I want to keep it that way.  From my understanding, that is the point of OAuth; the user clicks a link on my site that sends them to a Google page where they log in, and then Google redirects back to my app with the access token for the account they logged in with.  Sites like context.io and nimble.com do this, so I know it is possible.

Comment: The problem isn't my code, so I didn't include it.  I'm looking for an explanation of how to use the oauth_token/oauth_verifier that Google is returning me to access a gmail inbox.   My code works fine so far, I just don't know what to do next

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the demo? It seems to give all you need. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#demo

Comment: Gmail doesn't work with OAuth 2.0 yet.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-oauthplayground/eaS-tce9RxY/TP0wpkvRbroJ

Comment: My question is basically the same as this one, but it's not answered yet either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794715/extracting-gmail-username-with-oauth-access-token?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  There are two steps:

First, before you can actually access any of the user's information, you have to upgrade your Request Token to an Access Token.  This is the third step of the OAuth process (user authorization on Google's page being the second); I was confused about what the last step was exactly and was under the impression that the user was completing the second and third steps on Google's page.  [Google's OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) helped clear that up.  Anyways, after Google (or whoever your Service Provider is) redirects the user back to your app, you use the oauth_verifier and oauth_token to upgrade the Request Token into an Access Token.  Don't forget to use your oauth_token_secret (in addition to your consumer_secret_key) to generate the signature for this last request!  That little detail cost me a lot of time!  See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071955/whats-the-use-of-the-oauth-token-secret-in-twitter-oauth?rq=1) for more information on how to do that correctly.

Now, if you are like me, and want to  have Google handle which email address the user signs in with (as opposed to gather that info yourself within your app), you will need to make another request before you can access the user's inbox.  In my opinion, this is where Google's documentation really fails, as it seems that you will need the user's google id (gmail address) to use any of their APIs, yet it is possible to complete the OAuth process without ever getting it from the user.  This is what led to my confusion and was the point of my question.  I'm still not 100% clear on how you are supposed to do is, but what I've done for now is add 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/' to my scope, and call 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=0' to get an empty xml contact list that happens to contain the user's gmail address in it.  You can then parse the XML to get the user's email and go about your merry way.  It may also be possible (and perhaps preferable) to get the user's email using the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email' scope, but I haven't tried that yet.